# Whatsapp thumbnail preview showing in ioS and OS but not in Android

Tags: php, android, ios, whatsapp

```
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="./assets/media/logos/favicons/Sred.png?v=0.2">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="./assets/media/logos/favicons/Sred.png?v=0.2">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.spidergain.com/register">
<meta property="og:title" content="Spidergain">
<meta property="og:description" content="La rete nella quale tutti possono guadagnare, dal più piccolo al più grande influencer, dall’artigiano alla grande distribuzione">
```

I can't understand why the thumbnail is showing everywhere except Android phones. I have read 100 different solutions but nothing is working for me. It's a very strange problem because in a Whatsapp conversation I have with a friend my iPhone displays the thumbnail but the Android phone doesn't. Any ideas?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be a Whatsapp bug report, not be here